# JSTL foreach for list in list

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

I have controller that returns Set that consist of list of entities and one Long value.

```
    List<EventDto> events = eventService.getAllEventsPaging(page, size);
    Long dataBaseCount = eventRepository.count();
    Set<Object> pagingSet = new HashSet<Object>();
    model.addAttribute("events", pagingSet);
    return "events";
```

How could I reach fields from EventDto on jsp. I tried :

```
<c:forEach var="pagingSet.events" items="${pagingSet.events}">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${pagingSet.events.name}">
        </c:out></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Did you try to replace `var="pagingSet.events"` with `var="event"` and then invoke it `${event.name}`?

Comment: Why do you add `pagingSets` as `events` to the model?

Comment: Do you have entries in events?

Comment: @lifus yes i tried. It doesn't work

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk Alright then. It seems like `pagingSet` is empty and you meant to write `model.addAttribute("events",  events);` instead

Comment: @lifus Sorry, I edited my post and accidentally delete some code. It should be: List<EventDto> events = eventService.getAllEvents();
  Long dataBaseCount = eventRepository.count();
  Set<Object> pagingSet = new HashSet<Object>();
  pagingSet.add(events);
  pagingSet.add(dataBaseCount);
  model.addAttribute("events", pagingSet);
  
  return "events";

Comment: No worries. You may update your question. Anyway, your `pagingSet` now contains `List<EventDto>` and `Long` which isn't great since there is no such method like `Long#name`. You should actually `model.addAttribute("events", events);` and `model.addAttribute("dataBaseCount", dataBaseCount);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `forEach loop` in JSTL, the *var* is used as a reference to each element in the list of items in *items*. These two values should be different. It is essentially like writing `for (Object event : pagingSet.events)` in Java (code won't compile, just pseudocode).

Change your code to this and you should be fine:

```
<c:forEach var="event" items="${pagingSet.events}">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${event.name}">
        </c:out></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```